# FirebaseAuth Memory Leak in Activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, firebase, firebase-authentication, leakcanary

I added the awesome LeakCanary library in my app and pretty soon I started to receive various reports for a leak generated by the **FirebaseAuth** Object that I use in the various activities.

Now my question is: is it a leak generated by the Firebase library itself or I should destroy the object in onDestroy (setting it to null for instance)?

Here is the [report from LeakCanary](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wAdHbJe42IixjMDDZfv1kz8ecqgkMcRo4llREGVn_n0/edit?usp=sharing) and here is the [heapdump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3tbYe5XVMw9QlFwYjFvZnFmc0k/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is hidden in this line of the leak report:

```
* references com.ispimi.ispimi.DetailsFragment$4.this$0 (anonymous class implements com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener)
```

You need to make sure to remove any listener you added before your `Activity` is destroyed. Balance adding a listener with removing it. For example, if you added it in `onCreate` remove it in `onDestroy`. If you added it in `onStart` remove it in `onStop` and so on.

Comment: the funny story is that I was already doing it. But only for 1 out of 2 that I was instantianting. Thank you for the response